# Mounting a share with white spaces in name using Solaris

Tags: nfs, solaris, mount

I am trying to mount a file system on Solaris that includes white space in both target and source names. for example:

```
nas:/shares/windows/international/Financial Data/OEM/Connect Direct - /nfs/windows/international/Financial Data/OEM/Connect Direct nfs - yes rw,bg,retry=10,vers=3
```

But i get errors like:

> mount: Warning: Line for "Support/PSMS"" in vfstab has too many entries

So far I tried to:

- double quotes path names in vfstab,
- replace space \40 (like in Linux)
- escape with backslash.

None of these worked.

What is the proper way to mount shares containing white space both in target and source on Solaris?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Oracle [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/805-7228/6j6q7uev3/index.html) say this doesn't work

> Similarly, white space should not be used in a field value.

Comment: Here it's an entry from vfstaB:
   nas:"/ifs/windows/callcenter/fscustomercare/CSO Systems Support/PSMS" - "/nfs/callcenter/fscustomercare/CSO Systems Support/PSMS"  nfs - yes rw,bg,retry=10,vers=3

and if I try to mount it I get:

    mount: Warning: Line for "Support/PSMS"" in vfstab has too many entries